# The conversion of datetime2 date type to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have JQuery DatePicker and I am getting this error.

**ScheduleEntity :**

```
public int ID{get;set;}
public string Title{get;set;}
public string Location{get;set;}
public DateTime Date{get;set;}
```

**View :**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('#Date').datepicker{
    format:"dd/mm/yyyy"
    }).on('dp.change',function(e){
   $(this).data('datetimepicker').hide();
   });
</script>
```

I tried DataAnnotations datetime2 and Fluent API for datetime2 but not solved.

Comment: The error you show us is a SQL Server error, it's got nothing to do with MVC or Javascript.

Comment: @DavidG My column type is datetime on my SQL table. I changed my column type to string but this time I can't use FullCalendar with string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `EntityFramework`, you can standardize to datetime2 in your `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
}
```

This has solved a number of `DateTime` issues for me in the past.

Comment: I tried this;

modelBuilder.Entity<ScheduleEntity>()
.Property(x=>x.Date)
.HasColumnType("datetime2");

Not solved my problem but your solution solved. Thank you so much.